# How do I limit the number of guesses to 3 in Random Number Guessing Game

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Pick a number between 1 and 10"       
read ANS
echo "You guessed $ANS"
VALUE=$[( $RANDOM % 10 ) +1]
if [ "$VALUE" -eq "$ANS" ]; then
    echo "You win!"
elif [ "$VALUE" -gt "$ANS" ]; then
    echo "Higher!"
elif [ "$VALUE" -lt "$ANS" ]; then    
    echo "Lower!"
fi
```

Comment: Please do a search on Google or just read the docs. Looping is a basic and core topic in any imperative programming language. Take a look at http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

Comment: I've searched google and have check different answers on this site that never seem to work.  But thanks!  Will have a look!  Btw, this code works so far, I just didn't know how to post it without the lines in between.

Comment: Then post the code that you've tried that doesn't work - then we can help fix it. Asking us to code it for your, though, isn't what we do. We help fix broken code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#! /bin/bash

MAXTRIES=3
VALUE=$[( $RANDOM % 10 ) +1]

for (( i=1 ; i <= $MAXTRIES ; i++ )) ; do

    read -p "Pick a number between 1 and 10  " ANS

    echo "You guessed $ANS"

    if [ "$VALUE" -eq "$ANS" ]; then
        echo "You win!"
        break
    fi

    if [ $i -ge $MAXTRIES ] ; then
        echo "You have exceeded $MAXTRIES tries!"
        break

    elif [ "$VALUE" -gt "$ANS" ]; then
        echo "Higher!"

    elif [ "$VALUE" -lt "$ANS" ]; then
        echo "Lower!"
    fi

done
```